# Python: "IOError: C not found"

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am writing a python script that imports multiple input data files in csv format and plots statistical graphs. However I keep on getting an error which I am unable to figure out.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Here's the snippet of the relevant part of the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import Tkinter
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from Tkinter import Frame,Button,Canvas, Scrollbar, Tk, Checkbutton, W,E,N,S, VERTICAL, Y, BOTH, FALSE, TRUE, RIGHT, LEFT, Label, StringVar,IntVar
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, askopenfilenames
from tkMessageBox import askokcancel, showwarning
import sys


class MyGuiPlot(Frame):

    def open_csv(self): # open file + control defaultextension of it
        fname = askopenfilenames(defaultextension='.csv',
                  filetypes=[('CSV file','*.csv')])
        if fname:

            self.length = len(fname)
            self.get_data_multi(fname)               


    def get_data_multi(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

        # button_show_all = Button(self.root, text='Show all', command = lambda d = dataset, vars_all = vars_all,v=vars: self.var_states(v,dataset,vars_all))
        # button_show_all.grid(row = len(fname)+1, column=0, sticky = W)


        check_frame = Frame(self.root)
        check_frame.grid(row=1,columnspan=12,sticky=W)
        position = 0
        vars_all = []
        for data in range(len(fname)):
            j=0
            x=0
            print(data)
            vars = []
            #position = data*len(fname)
            dataset = np.genfromtxt(self.fname[data], dtype = float, delimiter = ',', names = True)
            file_name = Label(check_frame, text='DATASET{0} => {1}'.format(data,self.fname[data]))
            button_go = Button(check_frame, text= 'GO!', command = lambda dataset = dataset, v=vars: self.var_states(v,dataset))
            file_name.grid(row=position,column=0,columnspan=12, sticky=W)
            button_go.grid(row=position+3,columnspan=2, sticky=W)

            for _ in dataset.dtype.names:   # creating checkboxes
                var_ = StringVar()
                if _.startswith('x'):

                    ch_btn = Checkbutton(check_frame, text='{}'.format(str(data)+_), variable=var_, onvalue=str(data)+':'+_)
                    ch_btn.deselect()
                    ch_btn.grid(row=position+2,column=x, sticky=W)
                    x+=1

                    vars.append(var_)
                    vars_all.append(var_)
                else:
                    ch_btn = Checkbutton(check_frame, text='{}'.format(str(data)+_), variable=var_, onvalue=str(data)+':'+_)
                    ch_btn.deselect()
                    ch_btn.grid(row=position+1,column=j, sticky=W)
                    vars.append(var_)
                    j+=1
                    vars_all.append(var_)
            if len(fname) ==2:position +=len(fname)+2
            else:position +=len(fname)+1
        #print(vars_all)
        button_show_all = Button(self.root, text='Show all', command = lambda id=0: self.var_states(dataset = dataset,vars_all=vars_all))
        button_show_all.grid(row = len(fname)+1, column=0, sticky = W)
```

This is the error I get:

[image: Error]

Comment: Rather than post all that code and an image, you should post a tiny program that demonstrates the problem (hint: it's only when you call genfromtxt() that you have a problem--you can isolate that one line into a program that shows your issue).  Then you can replace the image with a copy of the error text itself.

Comment: In particular, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  By leaving `askopenfilenames` in the posted code, we cannot tell what you actually enter.  The traceback suggests that you entered 'C' and that there is no file named 'C'.  I also suggest upgrading to current 2.7.12.

Comment: you have problem in line with `dataset = ...` so use `print()` to see what you have in variables which you use in this line `print(data, self.fname, self.fname[data])` - i think you have path to file in `self.fname` and you get first char using `self.fname[data]`

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in line with `dataset = ...` so use `print()` to see what you have in variables which you use in this line `print(data, self.fname, self.fname[data])`

I think you have path to file in `self.fname` and you get first char using `self.fname[data]` and you use this single char as name in `np.genfromtxt()`

You use Windows so full path starts with `C:\` and first char is `C`
and now you see message `C not found`